# log4net file appender not creating a file

Tags: log4net

I have used log4net in the past without any trouble, however I am having some issues getting it to log to a file appender.  Very simple example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DebugFileAppender" type="log4net,Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="Logfile.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p [%d] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="DebugFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: <configSections>
 <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
<appender name="DebugFileAppender" type="log4net,Appender.FileAppender">
<file value="Logfile.log" />
 <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p [%d] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <!-- add other appenders here and the log messages will be sent to every listed appender -->
      <appender-ref ref="DebugFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

Answer (score 0):

Does the executing account have permission to write to the folder?

Comment: I think so.  I opened the permissions on the write directory

Comment: If that does not help, try turning on the internal log4net debugging. More info here:  
http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#internalDebug

Answer (score 0):

Try set write permission for the log folders for IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 0):

The comma in the type attribute should be replaced with a period: `type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender"`

You should be seeing an error similar to

```
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [file] of type [log4net,Appender.FileAppender]. Reported error follows.
...
```